# How join condition can be implemented?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am curious to understand how spark's join condition logic would like like in java, if implemented.

`Dataset<Row>` is a spark's in memory data structure. And `Row` can have multiple `Column`+s. So `Column` type also exists in framework.

For example below are two `Datasets<Row>`

```
Dataset<Row> one = ss.read().option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",")
                .csv("D:\\Notes\\data\\datasetOne.txt");

Dataset<Row> two = ss.read().option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",")
                .csv("D:\\Notes\\data\\datasetTwo.txt");
```

To join above two Datasets, Need to create condition for that. Like below

```
Column condition = (one.col("Name").notEqual("B")).
                        and(two.col("City").isNotNull()).
                        and(two.col("City").notEqual("C")).
                        and(two.col("Area").leq(400));

one.join(two,condition).select(one.select(*));
```

Am literally stuck to think forward, that What kind of `Column` instance gets created which look like above condition and to be able to use in join condition.

Can anyone share any simple example written in java which could show what's happening in the backend while executing `condition` code ? I mean to say the code which is able to allow `condition` instance of type `Column`

Am not able to imagine. Please share

Answer (score 0):

While joining 2 datasets, you should provide condition using fields of both datasets.
Let's say you want to capture records from 2 datasets where id and name column are matching.

You can do inner join as shown below:

```
Column condition = ds1.col("ID").equalTo(ds2.col("ID")).
                and(ds1.col("Name").equalTo(ds2.col("Name")));

Dataset<Row> joinedDS = ds1.join(ds2, condition, "inner");

// To filter records
joinedDS.where(ds2.col("name").notEqual("C"))
```

Comment: that I understand. But I want to know how Column class would like in java which could create Column instance which is holding above inner join condition.

Comment: No sure what you are asking but this is a java code and that's how we create column expression.

Comment: Column class is from scala. We can use scala class in java and java class in scala. https://livebook.manning.com/book/scala-in-action/chapter-11/